Type annotation for multiple inheritance
Consider the following minimal example:
class A:
    def f(self): pass
class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass
class D:
    def g(self): pass
class E(B,D): pass
class F(C,D): pass
AandD = ...
def h(obj: AandD): pass

The class A in my example can have a complex inheritance tree with many subclasses (B, C, etc.). I want that some instances of the subclasses of A have additional functionality g, so I introduced another class D and used multiple inheritance to define E and F.
How to annotate properly the parameter obj of the function h, which should accept instances that inherit from A and D simultaneously, i.e., what should be instead of AandD?
I know that I can define a protocol:
from typing import Protocol
class AandD(Protocol):
    def f(self): pass
    def g(self): pass

But I'd like to avoid repetitions in the code, since my classes contain a lot of methods. Also it won't work for a Python version prior to 3.8.
I'd also like to avoid using Union[E,F], since it will force me to update the list everywhere in my code, if I add a new subclass of A and D.

I just found a related question.
